# Naive Bayes in R: How to classify object into new "Unclassified" class

Tags: r, classification, naivebayes

So I have data set with objects of 4 classes. I'm using Naive Bayes classifier to classify new objects. Is it possible to determine if new object really shouldn't belong to any class (= somehow insert new class "Unclassified") ?

```
convert_counts <- function(x) {
x <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
x <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes"))
return(x)
}
sntcs_train1 <- apply(sntcs_train1, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)
sntcs_test1 <- apply(sntcs_test1, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)
library(e1071)
sntcs_classifier <- naiveBayes(sntcs_train1, sntcs_train$Author)
sntcs_test_pred <- predict(sntcs_classifier, sntcs_test1)
```

Comment: The straightforward approach would be to get some examples of data that should be "Unclassified", and feed them to `naiveBayes` (so you'll have 5 classes instead of 4). You might also think of a way of getting the probabilities by the algorithm with 4 classes and establish a criteria somehow ==> however that would be really arbitrary. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible. What you are using is a multinomial naive bayes classifier. The math can be expressed as follows:

```
                         P(B|A)*P(A)
  P(A|B) =           ____________________

           P(B|A)*P(A) + P(B|C)*P(C) +...+P(B|n)*P(n)
```

where A to n are the distinct classes that you want to classify and P(B|A) is the probability of B occurring given that A has occurred and P(A) is the probability of A occurring.

If you want to add some 5th "unclassified" classification, you have to figure out the following two values:

```
P(B| unclassified)*P(unclassified)
```

A the probability of being unclassified will simply be

```
1-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)-P(D)
```

for each of your 4 current classes. However you will still have to run the necessary analysis to figure out what your

```
P(B| unclassified)
```

term should be.